# MySQL: Join Tables But Remove Oldest Entries for Matching Field

Tags: mysql, join

I have two separate tables with the following data. I know finding the elements with the max value in a field is a common question, but I haven't found a way to do this in my situation where the data is spread over two tables.

Enrollment Table:

```
StudentID CourseID Section_Key Date_Added
```

Section Table:

```
SectionID Period
```

What I'm trying to do is show an entire student's schedule, but remove older courses that have been dropped. The Enrollment table includes courses that have been dropped so I want to only show the most recently added course for each Period.

For example, say there is a student with the following classes in their schedule:

```
CourseID Section_Key Period Date_Added
 2503F     123456      1     2018-05-13
 9990      245678      1     2018-08-01
```

I only want it to show the second course above in the results. I would also like the results sorted by Period.

Comment: Can you add a data example of your tables to the question?

Comment: It sounds like you want to group the results by studentid and period and take the record with the max date_added for each group. A bit like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363237/sql-request-with-group-by-and-max-and-join or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13697607/mysql-left-join-using-max-group-by-on-joined-table

Comment: @RyanDawson I think the MAX function might work, but how do I use it when the data is in two different tables? I need to find the max date for two classes of a single student that are in the same class period and Period and Date_Added are in different tables.